# Exception: 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown when there is 20,000+ data need to be bind in RadComboBox inside RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid, radcombobox

I have a **RadGrid** and a **RadComboBox outside** of RadGrid (say **comboOutside**), inside a Web Form.
Inside RadGrid, there is 1 more RadComboBox (say **comboRadGrid**). On selection of items from comboOutside, comboRadGrid is bind **i.e.,** If item 'Company' is selected from comboOutside, then all the company names will be bind in comboRadGrid; and then user select specific company from comboRadGrid and records are added in RadGrid.

For all items, functionality is working fine but I am facing issue in binding of a specific comboOutside item.
i.e., When I choose a specific item from comboOutside, say I have 100 items inside comboOutside, and when I select 35th items from it, then comboRadGrid always throw this error while binding records for 35th item (since 35th item has 2000+ records to bind in comboRadGrid)
Error is below:
[image]

Funcitonality is working fine for all the items except 1 specific item of RadComboBox. I don't understand why. Due to this I am unable to add records in RadGrid
Below is my code-
**C# code**

```
public DataTable GetAccCode(string CompanyCode)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[Invoice].[usp_tbl_AccountCode_DL_Test]", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyCode", CompanyCode);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return dt;
    }
protected void RGGSTAcCode_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
        {
            //bind dropdwon while "Add" 
            string CompanyCode = ddlCompany.SelectedValue.ToString();
            GridEditableItem item = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;

            //code to bind inside RadComboBox list   
            RadComboBox rcb = (RadComboBox)item.FindControl("ddlAccountCode");
            rcb.DataSource = GetAccCode(CompanyCode);
            rcb.DataTextField = "AccountDescription";
            rcb.DataValueField = "AccountCodeID";
            rcb.DataBind();
            rcb.Items.Insert(0, new RadComboBoxItem("- Select -", string.Empty));

            Session["AccCode"] = rcb.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string a = rcb.SelectedValue.ToString();

            //Select particular dropdown value while "Edit"
            Label lblAcCode2 = item.FindControl("lblAcCode2") as Label;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblAcCode2.Text))
            {
                rcb.SelectedValue = lblAcCode2.Text;
                rcb.SelectedItem.Text = lblAcCode2.Text;
            }
        }
    }
     //code to bind outside RadComboBox list
        protected void BindComapnyDL()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("General.usp_tbl_BuyerCode_Query", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            ddlCompany.DataTextField = "Title";
            ddlCompany.DataValueField = "Code";
            ddlCompany.DataSource = dt;
            ddlCompany.DataBind();

            Session["Comp"] = ddlCompany.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string a = ddlCompany.SelectedValue.ToString();      
        }

        //RadComboBox select index changed event
        protected void ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ddlCompany.SelectedValue == null || ddlCompany.SelectedValue == "")
            {
                GridCommandItem cmditem = (GridCommandItem)RGGSTAcCode.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem)[0];
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ctrl = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)cmditem.FindControl("AddNewRecordButton");
                ctrl.Enabled = false;

                System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton btn = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)cmditem.FindControl("InitInsertButton");
                btn.Enabled = false;

                string content = "Please select company first";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Successful", "alert('" + content + "');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                RGGSTAcCode.Rebind();
            }
        }
```

**HTML code**

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlCompany" runat="server" Height="200" Width="240"
          DropDownWidth="310" EmptyMessage="- Select Product -" HighlightTemplatedItems="true" CausesValidation="false"
          Filter="Contains" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AllowCustomText="true" AutoPostBack="true"
          DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Code" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>

<telerik:RadGrid ID="RGGSTAcCode" runat="server"
                   ShowFooter="True" GroupingEnabled="False" ShowStatusBar="true" EmptyDataText="No record available." 
                   AllowAutomaticInserts="False" AllowAutomaticUpdates="False" AllowAutomaticDeletes="true" 
                   OnNeedDataSource="RGGSTAcCode_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="RGGSTAcCode_ItemDataBound" 
                   OnInsertCommand="RGGSTAcCode_InsertCommand" OnDeleteCommand="RGGSTAcCode_DeleteCommand" 
                   OnUpdateCommand="RGGSTAcCode_UpdateCommand" OnItemCommand="RGGSTAcCode_ItemCommand">
                  <mastertableview ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true" autogeneratecolumns="false" datakeynames="AccountCodeID" InsertItemDisplay="Top"
                    insertitempageindexaction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage" ShowFooter="True" CommandItemDisplay="Top" ClientIDMode="Static">                                   
                         <Columns> 
                             <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn"></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn> 

                             <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AccountCode" HeaderText="Account Code">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") + " - " + Eval("AccountDescription")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                                   <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlAccountCode" runat="server" Height="200" Width="240"
                                       DropDownWidth="310" HighlightTemplatedItems="true" CausesValidation="true"
                                       Filter="Contains" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="AccountDescription" DataValueField="AccountCodeID">
                                   </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                             </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                             <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AccountDescription" HeaderText="Description" UniqueName="AccountDescription" SortExpression="AccountDescription" InsertVisiblityMode="AlwaysHidden" ReadOnly="true" ></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                             <telerik:GridBoundColumn aggregate="SUM" DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" FooterAggregateFormatString="Total : {0:###,##0.00}" DataFormatString="{0:n}" FooterStyle-BackColor="#ffc04c" UniqueName="Amount" SortExpression="Amount"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                             <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Remark" HeaderText="IFCA Remark" UniqueName="Remark" SortExpression="Remark">

                             </telerik:GridBoundColumn>    

                             <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmTextFormatString="Are you sure you want to Delete {0} Account Code?" ConfirmTextFields="AccountCodeID"
                             ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" UniqueName="DeleteColumn"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>                                                                            
                      </Columns>
                      <EditFormSettings>
                         <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
                      </EditFormSettings>
                      <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="Add new record" RefreshText="Refresh"></CommandItemSettings>
                  </mastertableview>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Please let me know why this error is coming for a specific item of `RadComboBox` selection.

Comment: Someone please please help me in this issue. I am new in asp.net and I am not getting how to resolve this in my Web application as I am facing this issue for a particular data. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please reply

Comment: For my 2 cents, I'd say use Ajax and lazy loading techniques to populate your grid and combo boxes. 2000+ items is a lot to load all at once and plus its probably taxing your database server. See the example here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/performance/virtualization/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I have to populate/bind the RadComboBox (comboRadGrid) which is inside of RadGrid, based on the Items that are outside of RadGrid of RadComboBox (comboOutside). I went through your suggested link but could not understood properly. I am very new in Telerik and asp.net Please let me know how to modify my comboRadGrid binding code (based on outside Combo List items) so that this issue do not occur again ? Please reply

Comment: For Combo Boxes, look at this link instead: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. Please read my posted question again. I have to bind the RadComboBox (which is inside the RadGrid), based on the Item values of RadComboBox which is outside of RadGrid. I am getting this error for only those records which has large data to bind inside comboRadGrid. If Possible please create a sample code for my better understanding as per my posted code. Please reply.

Comment: I tried to follow this link: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/how-to/radcombobox-in-radgrid  But now getting different error: *error during serialization or deserialization using the json javascriptserializer. The length of the string should exceed the value set on maxJSonLength preperty* Please someone reply. Help me to solve this issue

Comment: You need to set the maximum JSON size. Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to put this code in .aspx.cs page `public int MaxJsonLength { get; set; }` but still getting same error. Please reply what else I have to change in my code.

Comment: Used **LoadOnDemand** mechanish, by following this link: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx . This approach is used for large number of records to be bind in RadComboBox. And its working fine. Thank you @Icemanind for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used **LoadOnDemand** mechanish, by following this link:
 demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/… 
This approach is used for large number of records to be bind in RadComboBox which will avoid such exceptions to occur. And its working fine. 
Thank you @Icemanind for the help.